# Apache 2: I have multiple domain names I want to point to one Virtual Host. Do I use ServerAlias?

Tags: apache-2.2, serveralias

I have multiple domain names, for example:

1. www.foo.com
2. www.goo.com
3. www.moo.com
4. www.coo.com

I want all of these domain names to resolve to one website AND to redirect to **www.foo.com**

What is the best method to achieve this?

- Multiple  entries?
- Use ServerAlias?
- Something else?

If the best method is ServerAlias, what is the syntax?

```
ServerAlias www.goo.com, www.moo.com, www.coo.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ServerAlias` in a separate `VirtualHost` that does the redirection.

See the [apache docs for syntax details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias):

```
ServerAlias hostname [hostname] ...
```